# Minted package clash with `easylist` with `#` as list keyword

Tags: minted, easylist

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[sharp]{easylist} % use # symbol to denote a list
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{easylist}[enumerate]
# Profile Python
\begin{minted}{python}
import math
\end{minted}
\end{easylist}

\end{document}
```

To make it work, I could just use other symbols like `\usepackage[at]{easylist}` instead of `sharp`. But I am curious because error message cannn't really tell me why is this not working. Do someone know the why I cannot use `#`?

The error message is:

```
_./main.out.pyg:2:
Use of \FV@PYG doesn't match its definition.
\PYG #1#2->\FV@PYG {
                #1}{\FancyVerbBreakStart #2\FancyVerbBreakStop }
l.2 \PYG{k+kn}{import} \PYG{n+nn}{math}
```

---

## Update:

Please see @egreg's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/415731/81336) below (and comments!) for an explanation.

A solution to the above question using `\Activate` and `\Deactivate` command provided by `easylist`.:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[sharp]{easylist} % use # symbol to denote a list
\usepackage[cache=false]{minted}
\title{useless}
\begin{document}

\begin{easylist}[enumerate]
# Deactivate it first,
\Deactivate
\begin{minted}{python}
import math
\end{minted}
\Activate
# then activate it again.
# Good!
\end{easylist}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does it make sense to use `minted` inside `easylist` to begin with?

Comment: I think yes. Because if I use a different symbol, there would be no problem. Also, a vague analogy is that since `verbatim` works in `easylist`, why not `minted`? @egreg

Comment: Possibly the answer is that the symbol `#` is used in `minted`. And since `minted` is loaded in `easylist`, `easylist` adjust what `#` means and this clashes with `minted`. So the choice would only be use another symbol for `easylist`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sharp` option makes `#` into an active character. The files that are produced by `pygmentize` contain macro definitions which in turn use `#` and, because of being inside `easylist`, this character is no longer the parameter specifier.

Thus all the auxiliary macros with argument that `minted` needs to use don't work as expected.

Using other characters can lead to other problems; I tried the `at` option and `@` won't work in `minted`. For example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[at]{easylist} % use # symbol to denote a list
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{easylist}[enumerate]
@ Profile Python
\begin{minted}{python}
    @classmethod
\end{minted}
\end{easylist}

\end{document}
```

will not print `@`.

Besides, `minted` will not respect the current indentation in the list.

Here's a comparison:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{easylist}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Profile Python
\begin{minted}{python}
# This program prints Hello, world!
print('Hello, world!')
\end{minted}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Indented
\begin{minted}{python}
# This program prints Hello, world!
print('Hello, world!')
\end{minted}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\begin{easylist}[enumerate]
§ Profile Python
\begin{minted}{python}
# This program prints Hello, world!
print('Hello, world!')
\end{minted}
§§ Indented
\begin{minted}{python}
# This program prints Hello, world!
print('Hello, world!')
\end{minted}
\end{easylist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good explanation! It's strange that `@` does not work for you though.

Comment: @taper Try `@classmethod` in the Python code. The `@` will disappear. I added a full example.

Comment: Oh.. Sure. Then I found, among documented keywords, `§` to be a fairly good choice. Since it is rarely used, could be inputed by `\S` when needed, and is available on my keyboard (:P).

Comment: Hi @egreg, I just found in `easylist`'s documentation there is a way to circumvent this problem. It is updated in my question.

Comment: @taper And now, where’s the advantage over using a regular `\item`?

Comment: Because I usually want multiply indented ones, like those popular in Word/OneNote (called `Harvard style` in Pages). And it is a terrible experience to work with multiple `\begin{enumerate} \item \begin{enumerate} \item \begin{...} OMG \end...`. Whereas in `easylist`, this task is super easy.

Comment: @taper With the non negligible disadvantage that `minted` does not follow the indentation of the list, whereas it does with `enumerate`.

Comment: @taper I added a visual comparison.

Comment: Good illustration. I think we could think of `easylist` as one best in writing quick notes (as is actually what I want to achieve with it), where I do not care too much about the indentation and look, but care very much about convenience. But in you case, it would certainly be more appropriate to use `enumerate`.